# Count number of gaps in a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to count the number of gaps in a numpy array. In this case the consecutive zeros count as one gap.

```
array = np.array([   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
        1692, 1692, 1692, 1692, 1692, 1692, 1692, 2458, 2458, 2458, 2458,
        2458, 2458, 2458,    0,    0,    0, 3956, 3956, 3956, 3956, 3956,
        3956, 3956,    0,    0,    0,    0, 5431, 5431, 5431, 5431, 5431,
        5431, 5431,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0])
```

In the above array there are 4 gaps, so my output should be 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean array and count the values that are True when the previous one is False:

```
a = array==0
(a&~np.r_[[False],a[:-1]]).sum()
```

output: `4`

Answer (score 1):

Please see the optimised version of the accepted answer (2.5x faster). It is faster because it is not necessary to concatenate (`np.r_`) the numpy arrays

```
a = array == 0
(a[1:] & ~a[:-1]).sum() + a[0]
```

Comparison:

```
%%timeit
a = array == 0
(a&~np.r_[[False],a[:-1]]).sum()
```

**17.4 µs ± 39.4 ns** per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
a = array == 0
(a[1:] & ~a[:-1]).sum() + a[0]
```

**6.75 µs ± 12.7 ns** per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)